# What is the most efficient way to find a penny in an empty field?

Tags: geometry, algorithms

Let's say that I'm in a rectangular field,2 miles in width and 3 in length, with a metal detector. I know that somewhere within this field lies a penny, which is equally likely to be at any point. My metal detector will detect any penny within a 30-ft radius of my location. Furthermore, this penny is the only metallic object in the field (at least as far as my metal detector is concerned). I want to minimize my metal detector's battery usage. Of course, I'll turn off my metal detector when I walk back to a place I've already been to.

Comment: What is the definition of efficient here? Because if it's just battery use, then how is it spent? If I turn it on for a moment, do I get to detect anything within 30 ft instantly? Then I could walk around, flip it on for an arbitrarily small time, and then move elsewhere. That seems trivial, though.

Comment: "Efficient" simply means using as little battery life as possible. Also, the metal detector detects metal as soon as it is turned on. However, what I want is for the detector to be on somewhat continuously.

Comment: Unless you have something more specific than somewhat continuos, I don't really know how to help. Optimization is all about edge cases. So defining the limitations is a critical part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking something like this. Basically we divide a rectangle into halves, eighths, etc. until we find what we're looking for.

First, I walk along each each diagonal
Second, I walk along the center lines of the rectangle and thereby divide the rectangle into smaller rectangles.
I then repeat these two steps with each rectangle until I find the penny.

Comment: You should have included this as part of the question, since these are thoughts and not a mathematical answer. It is a nice question, by the way.